# Lower semicontinuity on a metric space

Tags: metric-spaces, continuity

I'm trying to prove something about lower semicontinuity for a map on a metric space $(X,d)$. I will try to write here my idea of the proof, hope someone can approve or contest it.

**Def.** Let $(X,d)$ be a metric space and $\emptyset \neq C \subset X$. Let $F(X)$ denote the family of non empty, closed subset of $X$ and $T:C→F(X)$ a multivalued mapping. We say that T has the property $(S)$ if

$(S)$ $\forall \epsilon>0$ and $x \in X$ there exist $\delta>0$ such that $y\in B_{\delta}[x] \cap C$ implies that $$d(u,Tx)<\epsilon,$$
for all $u \in Ty$. Where $B_{\delta}[x]=\{y\in X : d(y,x)\leq\delta\}$.

Now, let me introduce the Lemma I'm trying to prove:

**Lemma.** Let $(X,d)$ be a metric space and $\emptyset \neq C \subset X$. Let $F(X)$ the family of non empty, closed subset of $X$ and $T:X→F(X)$ a multivalued mapping. If $T$ has the property $(S)$ then the function $$\phi: C→R^{+},$$
such that $\phi(x)=d(x,Tx)$ for all $x \in C$, is lower semicontinuous.

*Proof.* We want to show that if $\{x_n\}\subset C$ and $\{x_n\}$ converges to $x \in C$ then $$\phi(x)\leq \liminf \phi(x_n).$$
Fix $x\in C$ and $\{x_n\}$ such that $x_n→x$. Because $T$ has the property $(S)$, then, for fixed $\epsilon>0$ there exist $0<\delta<\frac{\epsilon}{4}$ such that $y\in B_{\delta}[x] \cap C$ implies that $$d(u,Tx)<\epsilon,$$ for all $u \in Ty$.
Because $x_n→x$ then, for fixed $\delta$, there exist $n(\delta) \in \mathbb{N}$ such that $d(x_n,x)<\delta$ for all $n\geq n(\delta)$. Hence, for all $n\geq n(\delta)$, we have $$x_n\in B_{\delta}[x] \cap C,$$ and so $d(u,Tx)<\epsilon$ for all $u \in T x_n$. Fix $x_n$ such that $n\geq n(\delta)$. Because $$d(x_n,T x_n)= inf\{d(x_n,u): u \in T x_n\},$$ then there exist $u\in T x_n$ such that $$d(x_n,u)\leq d(x_n, T x_n)+ \frac{\epsilon}{2}.$$ Similarly we can choose $v \in Tx$ such that $d(u,v)\leq\frac{\epsilon}{4}$. 
Thus

$$ d(x,Tx)-[d(x_n,Tx_n)+\frac{\epsilon}{2}]\leq d(x,Tx)-d(x_n,u)\leq d(x,x_n)+d(x_n,u)+d(u,Tx)-d(x_n,u) \leq d(x,x_n)+d(u,Tx) \leq d(x_n,x)+d(u,v) \leq \delta + \frac{\epsilon}{4} \leq \frac{\epsilon}{2},$$ and hence
$$d(x,Tx)-d(x_n,Tx_n)\leq \epsilon.$$ So $\phi$ is lower semicontinuous.

This is my idea of the proof. Anyone can help me???